# how to parse db date information to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, database, date, time

I have some data which is coming from backend

in my data there are a key whit name **createdAt: "2022-09-30T21:39:17.489Z"**

i want to parse this value to **yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm**

at first i thought to create a function which will take the value and slice it like this

```
export const convertDate = (value) => {

        const time = value.slice(11, 16); // 21:39
        const date = value.slice(0, 10); // 2022-09-30

        return `${date} ${time}`
}
```

but then i thought maybe i can find other way to solve this problem

Comment: You can use this library: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: There is nothing wrong with simple string manipulation. Converting to a *Date* then formatting is less efficient, more complex and simply not necessary. The format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm is typically interpreted as local, whereas the original timestamp is UTC.

Comment: Another solution that just reformats the string is to use a regular expression to extract the bits you want, e.g. `let [date, time] = s.match(/\d+[\-\:]\d+(-\d+)?/g) || [];`, however the OP code is likely more efficient and maintainable.